# find distance between two geo point with direction android

Tags: android, gps

i am able to find distance between two geolocation by two Location objects

here is below

```
       mLoc.distanceTo(mLocTarget)
```

**mLoc** is current user Location and **mLocTarget** is target location of android

now i want to find direction also means like

16m. West or 16m. North is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find Direction between two locations by Bearing.

[public float bearingTo (Location dest)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#bearingTo%28android.location.Location%29)

Comment: I think answer of @PeterJ was correct, I posted wrong link here.

Answer (score 6):

getBearing() returns the instantaneous bearing, but for between to points use:

[public float bearingTo (Location dest)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#bearingTo%28android.location.Location%29)